# Org mode quote block indentation (highlighting)

Tags: org-mode, highlighting

Can indentation of the Org mode quote block be configured? I would like to highlight quote blocks with indented margins, both left and right if possible:

[image]

The example above demonstrates `org-quote` *face* properties (e.g.: `:height` `:foreground`, etc.) modified in my theme. However the left and right margins shown in the quote block are faked using spaces. Perhaps indentation is set by `wrap-prefix`, which is a [special text property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties)? If this is the right direction, how could I set a custom `wrap-prefix` for org-quote blocks only?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done quite easily during font-lock by adding a custom function to `org-font-lock-hook`. This works well unless you use `org-indent-mode`, which recalculates and overrides `line-prefix` and `wrap-prefix` after buffer changes.

```
(add-hook 'org-font-lock-hook #'aj/org-indent-quotes)

(defun aj/org-indent-quotes (limit)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_quote" limit t)
      (let ((beg (1+ (match-end 0))))
        ;; on purpose, we look further than LIMIT
        (when (search-forward-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+end_quote" nil t)
          (let ((end (1- (match-beginning 0)))
                (indent (propertize "    " 'face 'org-hide)))
            (add-text-properties beg end (list 'line-prefix indent
                                               'wrap-prefix indent))))))))
```

I don’t think there is an easy way of making it wrap earlier at the end of line, i.e. right indent (there is no “`wrap-suffix`” property).

Answer (score 0):

I think the feature you want does not exist yet.  Further I think the answer of Anders Johansson is great.

This is a slightly different ansatz and only a start using the org element api:

```
(defun mw-org-left-margin-for-quote-blocks ()
"Insert a tab as left margin for every org quote block."
(interactive)
(let ((data (org-element-parse-buffer)))
    (org-element-map data 'quote-block
      (lambda (ele)
        (put-text-property
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (org-element-property :begin ele))
           (beginning-of-line 2)
           (point))
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (org-element-property :end ele))
           (end-of-line -1)
           (point))
         'line-prefix "\t")))))
```