# Change background color of quote block

Tags: org-mode, faces

I have a theme in which I specified how my source blocks and quote blocks look:

`` `(org-block ((,class (:foreground ,fg3 :background ,"#fffce9"))))
`(org-block-begin-line ((,class (:foreground ,"#996600" :background ,"#ffe6b3"))))
`(org-block-end-line ((,class (:foreground ,"#996600" :background ,"#ffe6b3"))))
`(org-quote ((,class (:foreground ,"#2f4f4f" :background ,"#f0fef0" :slant italic)))) ``

This works well for the source block, but is ignored for the quote block (see screenshot).

[image: Example org file with source and quote block]

When I inspect the face via M-x customize-face org-quote, it seems it seems my customizations are being applied:

[image: org-quote customization]

Judging from [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38570/org-mode-quote-block-indentation-highlighting) post, it should be possible.

Any help on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customize variable `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks`.

From the documentation of `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks`:

> Non-nil means, add a special face to #+begin_quote and #+begin_verse
>   block. When nil, format these as normal Org.  This is the default,
>   because the content of these blocks will still be treated as Org
>   syntax.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Precisely the question I had, precisely the answer I needed.  Thanks!